# How to resolve: "resolving package versions" in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am new to the programming language Julia. I ran a few mixed models using the `MixedModels` package. Then, i wanted to run some average marginal effects using the `Effects` package. However, i get an error (see below).

To solve this issue, i tried to update all packages by using `Pkg.update()`. Then, i tried to install a particular version of the `Effects` package by using `Pkg.rm("Effects") Pkg.add("Effects", v"0.1.4")`. However, none of these options solved the issue. Could someone point out to me please what am i doing wrong?

```
Pkg.add("Effects")

    Resolving package versions...
Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Effects [8f03c58b]:
 Effects [8f03c58b] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0-0.1.4 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.1.0-0.1.4
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left

Stacktrace:
 [1] propagate_constraints!(::Pkg.Resolve.Graph, ::Set{Int64}; log_events::Bool) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Resolve/graphtype.jl:1005
 [2] propagate_constraints! at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Resolve/graphtype.jl:946 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [3] simplify_graph!(::Pkg.Resolve.Graph, ::Set{Int64}; clean_graph::Bool) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Resolve/graphtype.jl:1460
 [4] simplify_graph! at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Resolve/graphtype.jl:1460 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [5] resolve_versions!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:375
 [6] targeted_resolve at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1114 [inlined]
 [7] tiered_resolve(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1100
 [8] _resolve at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1120 [inlined]
 [9] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.MacOS) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1135
 [10] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.MacOS, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:188
 [11] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:139
 [12] #add#21 at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [13] add at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [14] #add#20 at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:66 [inlined]
 [15] add at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:66 [inlined]
 [16] add(::String; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:65
 [17] add(::String) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:65
 [18] top-level scope at In[216]:1
 [19] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1091
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using Julia version 1.5, but all existing versions of the Effects package require at least Julia version 1.6 (see [Effects/Compat.toml](https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General/blob/1dca3fe19e2823f83d3155dabed3411211688934/E/Effects/Compat.toml#L6)). If you can, you should upgrade Julia to 1.6 since that is (at the time of writing) the supported stable version.

---

To explain the error message a bit:

```
Effects [8f03c58b] log:
├─possible versions are: 0.1.0-0.1.4 or uninstalled
├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.1.0-0.1.4
└─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
```

The resolver starts with all existing versions as options ([0.1.0-0.1.4](https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General/blob/1dca3fe19e2823f83d3155dabed3411211688934/E/Effects/Versions.toml)) including the option to not have the package installed at all (`uninstalled`).

The second line filters out the `uninstalled` option since you are requesting it to be installed (`explicit requirement`). `*` is a version wildcard which just means that you have not requested a specific version to be installed.

The third line is then causing the error, due to requirements on the Julia version all the remaining options are filtered out and you get `no versions left`, i.e. no more remaining options.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but updating Julia seems not to have fully resolved the issue. There is still some strange error that i am getting, i updated my question above. Could you let me know what you think please?

Comment: That seems to be a completely different problem -- it is a usage error and has nothing to do with package installation as your first question. You should ask a new question about that.